# Share with UIActivityViewController - Black Facebook Icon

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

Some of AppStore application(like SoundCloud) is showing `UIActivityViewController` with `Facebook` icon two times if you have configure FB app and in device settings.

One is Black FB icon, I'm Not sure how its possible. I need to do same. i.e even if user is not configure FB in setting or FB app that time there must me FB icon with `UIActivityViewController`, and tap on it will popup UI to login in FB.

Comment: do you have a screenshot for the 2 things? Can you elaborate with code on what you are trying to do?